What’s a bug breach in Helldivers 2?
Sometimes when playing bug missions in Helldivers 2, there’ll be a pop-up on the HUD that says there’s been a bug breach.
What does this mean exactly?

A bug breach is an enemy spawn event, separate from the spawns related to points of interest, in a similar fashion to bots shooting flares (and ships dropping more bots) and squid lights shooting 3 white flares (and ships dropping more squids).
When a bug breach happens, an orange plume of smoke comes out of a particular spot on the ground, and bugs will begin spawning by crawling out of the ground at that location.
Unlike hive spawners, I don't believe there is a way to disable them early, by throwing a grenade for example, though they are short-lived and will stop spawning enemies after about 30 seconds. Napalm is particularly effective at countering them.
